# how to fix Unable to open MTP device '[usb:004,010]' in ubuntu 1V

Tags: usb, nautilus, mtp

I connected my Lumia 640 mobile to Ubuntu and when I tried to open it shows this error:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you, either it's not correctly mounted or you need to correct the access rights for FS "Lumia...".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically eject drivers disk when mounting Android phone?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/658033/how-to-automatically-eject-drivers-disk-when-mounting-android-phone)

Comment: Sry I linked a wrong question. Here is the correct one. http://askubuntu.com/questions/668164/how-create-a-udev-rules-to-disable-one-of-android-devices

Answer (score 11):

Install [gMTP](https://gmtp.sourceforge.io/) (simple file transfer program for MTP based devices). In the terminal (to open a terminal window, press <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + T</kbd>; to close it, press <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd>), type:

```
sudo apt install gmtp
```

It's not perfect, but better than nothing.

**Tip**: When you're successfully connected, enable "Folder view" in the menu.

- [Homepage](https://gmtp.sourceforge.io/)
- On [package.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/gmtp)

Comment: If `go-mtpfs` return `OpenSession failed: LIBUSB_ERROR_IO; attempting reset` or `mtp-detect`, `libusb_get_active_config_descriptor(1) failed: No data available`; check if something like `usbguard` is blocking your device. If the folder appears empty, check the message to allow access on your phone :)

Comment: Not working .. it also sys error "Unable to Connect Raw device"

Answer (score 3):

The Solution is the same as the one above from @namelesseke but with Ubunut 18.10 and nautilus 3.26.4 the error message is different, i.e. the error says something like

> Unhandled error message: The name 1.994 was not provided by any
>   service files

After installing gmtp with

```
$ sudo apt-get install gmtp
```

everything worked like charm.

Comment: This solved the issue for me within Files(nautilus) with ubuntu 20.04. e.g. my phone is a HuaweiP9. After upgrate to ubuntu 20.04, usb connect phone, "EVA L09" appears in Files(nautilus) then "Allow access to files mtp" then error mtp "unhandled error message: The name 1.1630 was not provided by any .service files". Problem. After install of gmtp then mtp connection showed up ok in Files(nautilus).